# Есть ли в Go функция indexOf?

Tags: golang

Иль придется искать нужный элемент через range и if внутри. Если нет, то какой быстрый вариант можно сделать (быстрый, в смысле по скорости).

Comment: На enSO говорят что нет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307478

Comment: если последовательность не отсортированная, то только полный перебор.

Comment: к сожалению, нету

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, такая функция отсутствует. В таких случаях всё же используется for-range цикл с проверкой внутри. Пример:

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func indexOf(arr []string, need string) int {
    for ind, val := range arr {
        if val == need {
            return ind
        }
    }
    return -1
}

func main() {
    arr := []string{"foo", "bar"}
    fmt.Println(indexOf(arr, "foo")) // Output: 0
    fmt.Println(indexOf(arr, "qwe")) // Output: -1
}
```

Дженерики уже в бете версии Go 1.18 (UPD: Go 1.18 уже вышел), и поэтому можно сделать такую реализацию функции:

```go
func indexOf[T any](arr []T, need T) int {
    for ind, val := range arr {
        if val == need {
            return ind
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

и вызывать через `indexOf[string]([]string{"qwe", "42"}, "123")` или же без типа: `indexOf([]string{"qwe", "42"}, "123")`